# Вывести категории woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress

Всем привет.
Не могу вывести категории на отдельной странице.
Нужно вывести все категории и подкатегории основной категории на которой находимся.
То есть, например зашли на страницу родительской категории, нужно чтобы тут выводились все дочерние категории, потом зашли в дочернюю и чтобы тут тоже выводились все дочерние категории родительской.
Есть такой код, но он выводит подкатегории только на странице родительской категории.

```
    <?php $category = get_queried_object();

$args = array(
    'child_of' => $category->term_id,
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
    'hide_empty' => false,
);
$product_categories = get_terms( $args ); 
foreach ( $product_categories as $product_category ) { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $product_category ); ?>" class="cat-btn"><?php echo $product_category->name; ?></a>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: up!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

`$category->term_id` - возращает id родительской категории?

Так-же `child_of` выводит всех потомков. Используй `parent` если необходимо   получить прямы потомков

Comment: это ответ или уточняющий/новый вопрос?

Comment: Уточняющий вопрос

Comment: нужно вывести все дочерние категории на каждой странице родительской категории. Пример можно посмотреть тут https://esh-derevenskoe.ru/milk-cheese-and-eggs